# MySQL CONCAT_WS three columns, echo result in foreach loop after explode()

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, explode, concat-ws

I have this as result from `MySQL` (stored as `$result`)

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| CONCAT_WS('::', p.isMobile, p.contact_phone_id, p.contact_phone_number) |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 0::1::123                                                               |
| 1::2::456                                                               |
| 0::3::789                                                               |
| 1::4::987                                                               |
| 0::5::654                                                               |
| 0::6::321                                                               |
| 1::7::123                                                               |
| 1::11::456                                                              |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Then in a while loop I use `explode()` for each row like: `explode('::', $result)`. How can I use `foreach()` to output data like this (first three rows in `while` iteration as example):

```
Row 1: The first column is 0, the second column is 1, the third column is 123
Row 2: The first column is 1, the second column is 2, the third column is 456
Row 3: The first column is 0, the second column is 3, the third column is 789
```

Comment: Why are you concatenating your column values together just to split them apart again?

Comment: Because in my project, there is other columns aswell but for the purpose of this thread I excluded that code.

Comment: @David That's not a (valid) reason

Answer (score 0):

There's really no good reason to use a foreach for the output here. It'd be much easier to just explode(), and then output the fields as you want them 
(note that I constructed an array and used array_shift() over it to simulate fetching rows from a database):

```
<?php
$data = ['0::1::123', '1::2::456', '0::3::789', '1::4::987', '0::5::654', '0::6::321', '1::7::123', '1::11::456'];

$rownum = 0;
while($row = array_shift($data)) {
    echo "Row $rownum: ";
    $fields = explode('::', $row);
    echo "The first column is {$fields[0]}, the second column is {$fields[1]}, the third column is {$fields[2]}";
    echo "\n";
    ++$rownum;
}
```

However, if you're really attached to using `foreach` for the problem, you'll first want to construct yourself an array of "position names" (first, second, third, etc.), and then loop over THAT, and pull the same key from the $row array as you generate the output:

```
<?php
$data = ['0::1::123', '1::2::456', '0::3::789', '1::4::987', '0::5::654', '0::6::321', '1::7::123', '1::11::456'];

$positions = ['first', 'second', 'third'];

$rownum = 0;
while($row = array_shift($data)) {
    echo "Row $rownum: ";
    $fields = explode('::', $row);
    $output = "";
    foreach($positions as $pos => $posName) {
        $output .= "the {$posName} column is {$fields[$pos]}, ";
    }
    $output = substr($output, 0, -2); // trim that trailing comma

    echo "$output\n";
    ++$rownum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$rowNumber = 1;
foreach($result as $value)
{
    $field = explode('::', $value);
    echo "Row {$rowNumber}: The first column is {$filed[0]}, the second column is {$field[1]}, the third column is {$field[2]}\n";

    $rowNumber++;
}
```